# Bind layout to screen resolution

Tags: java, javafx

My layout looks like that:

[image]

Panel is a `VBox` and Content is a `HBox`. Both are contained in an `HBox`.
I need to make panel fixed size, so right now I'm doing it like that:

```
VBox panel = new VBox();
double fixedWidth = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth() / 10;
panel.setMinWidth(fixedWidth);
panel.setMaxHeight(fixedWidth);
```

... but what if user's screen resolution change? That code doesn't handle that and I'm afraid the `Screen` class doesn't provide any type of callback.

Comment: Do you want `panel` to be a fixed width, or do you want want its width to be 10% of the screen width?  It appears you want it to be 10% of the screen width, which is not the same as having a fixed width.

Comment: what's the problem exactly? fx is designed to handle different resolutions auto-magically, provided the developer doesn't hinder it by hard-coding sizes/constraints <g>

Answer (score 2):

Your title and most of your question indicate you want `panel` to use 10% of the screen’s width, and `content` to use 90% of the screen’s width.  However, you also use the term “fixed width” which is something different;  namely, that `panel` would have the same width at all times, regardless of screen size.

I shall assume you meant the first concept:  that you want `panel` to use 10% of the width and `content` to use 90% of the width.

Instead of an HBox, use a [GridPane](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html).  Set its [column constraints](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#getColumnConstraints()) to 10% and 90%.

```
ColumnConstraints panelWidth = new ColumnConstraints();
panelWidth.setPercentWidth(10);
panelWidth.setFillWidth(true);

ColumnConstraints contentWidth = new ColumnConstraints();
contentWidth.setPercentWidth(90);
contentWidth.setFillWidth(true);

RowConstraints rowConstraints = new RowConstraints();
rowConstraints.setFillHeight(true);
rowConstraints.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

GridPane pane = new GridPane();
pane.addRow(0, panel, content);
pane.getColumnConstraints().setAll(panelWidth, contentWidth);
pane.getRowConstraints().setAll(rowConstraints);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current solution, you seem to be giving 10% size to your panel which means 90% is the content panel. You can directly bind screen size to your scene object and initialize your scene with screen size. It will make the whole application reactive to the screen resolution changes. Here is a sample from my code on how I do it:

```
final Scene scene = new Scene(root,width,height);
            
            logger.debug("Scene Created");
            stage.centerOnScreen();
            stage.setScene(scene);
           
            final ChangeListener<Number> listener = new ChangeListener<Number>()
            {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, final Number newValue)
                    {
                        logger.debug("Scene Resize Started");
                        Scale scale = new Scale();
                        scale.xProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().divide(width));
                        scale.yProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().divide(height));
                        scale.setPivotX(0); scale.setPivotY(0);
                        root.getTransforms().clear();
                        root.getTransforms().addAll(scale);
                        logger.debug("Scene Resize Ended");
                          
                    }
            };
            
            scene.widthProperty().addListener(listener);
            scene.heightProperty().addListener(listener);
```

This takes care of resize as well as resolution changes. The width and height variable in the start are width and height captured from Screen of the user.